# Accumulate in MPI_Send and MPI_Recv using C++

Tags: c++, mpi

Here is my entire code first (the code is correct):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int mynode, totalnodes;
    int sum,starval,endval,accum;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init (&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes); //get totalnodes
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode);    //get mynode

    sum=0; //zero sum for accumulation
    starval = 1000*mynode / totalnodes+1;
    endval = 1000*(mynode+1) / totalnodes;

    for (int i=starval; i <= endval; i=i+1)
        sum = sum + i;
    if(mynode!=0)
        MPI_Send(&sum,1,MPI_INT,0,7,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    else
    for(int j=1; j < totalnodes; j=j+1){
        MPI_Recv(&accum,1,MPI_INT,j,7,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        sum=sum+accum;
    }
    if(mynode ==0)
        cout << "the sum from 1 to 1000 is: " << sum << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

We are trying to seperate the accumulating assignment to all different processors, and then accumulating result made by all processor (not the processor 0) to send the outcome to the processor 0. And the processor zero will accumulating all the outcomes receieved from other processors, and output a result of the summation from 1 to 1000 (As you can see in the code).

Now, my question is: what is the "accum" in the command of
`sum = sum + accum;`
There is no declearation of "accum". How does the operation system know that?

Please brifly explain the logic of

`else`

`for(int j=1; j < totalnodes; j=j+1){`

`MPI_Recv(&accum,1,MPI_INT,j,7,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);`

`sum=sum+accum;}`

And what did the `accum` did in this code.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: ```accum``` is defined as int in the second line of the function. Also I might add that this exercise is somewhat pointless and not the recommended way of using MPI. There is an [```MPI_Reduce```](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man3/MPI_Reduce.3.php) that does exactly what you want, just more efficiently

Comment: Is this a class assignment? What have you managed to do to get the answer?

Comment: Choose better names for your local variables! In this case, global_sum and local_sum are better fit than sum and accum.